# Importing big sql file ends up with [ERROR_RDBMS] exit status 1

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to import a big sql file (around 10GB) in Google SQL. I have create my instance and had tried so far with MySQL 5.6 and MySQL 5.7 both getting the same issue when trying to import the database: `[ERROR_RDBMS] exit status 1`. I have tried the user interface method for import as well as the console one (`gcloud sql import sql mydb gs://my-path/mydb.sql --database=mydb`). Also tried to find more details in Log explorer, but there was no error or anything else be notices for the mysql.err log.

In the same time I manage to connect my MySQL Workbench to the instance and I could see that there where few database tables that were imported. The only import seems that crushed on importing one of the biggest tables which is around 5GB.

Can anyone suggest what might cause this error and how I can find more info about it. Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest checking if the Cloud SQL service account has the correct permissions, namely `storage.objectAdmin`, as this is the most likely reason for the error as noted in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing#importing_data_from_a_sql_dump_file_in). Separately, make sure the export file is generated according to the guidelines shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting#export-mysqldump)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found how to see the error on google console but figure it our that I can import the database through the MySQL Workbench and there I got the full error. If any one know a way to do this on the google cloud I'll accept her/his answer.